# Twitter The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 6.)?

Tags: ios, twitter

I want to upload image to Twitter.

I wrote code as

```
- (void)postImage:(UIImage *)image withStatus:(NSString *)status
{
    NSLog(@"Share on Twitter");

    ACAccountType *twitterType =
    [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    SLRequestHandler requestHandler =
    ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if (responseData) {
            NSInteger statusCode = urlResponse.statusCode;
            if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300) {
                NSDictionary *postResponseData =
                [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                  error:NULL];
                NSLog(@"[SUCCESS!] Created Tweet with ID: %@", postResponseData[@"id_str"]);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"[ERROR] Server responded: status code %d %@", statusCode,
                      [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:statusCode]);
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"[ERROR] An error occurred while posting: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    };

    ACAccountStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler accountStoreHandler =
    ^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {
            NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:twitterType];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com"
                          @"/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json"];
            NSDictionary *params = @{@"status" : status};
            SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                                    requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                              URL:url
                                                       parameters:params];
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.f);
            [request addMultipartData:imageData
                             withName:@"media[]"
                                 type:@"image/jpeg"
                             filename:@"image.jpg"];
            [request setAccount:[accounts lastObject]];
            [request performRequestWithHandler:requestHandler];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"[ERROR] An error occurred while asking for user authorization: %@",
                  [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    };

    [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType
                                               options:NULL
                                            completion:accountStoreHandler];
}
```

I am getting error as

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 6.)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `SLComposeViewController` class. In order to do this, a number of steps should be performed in sequence. Firstly, the application may optionally check to verify whether a message can be sent to the specified social network service. This essentially equates to checking if a valid social network account has been configured on the device and is achieved using the `isAvailableForServiceType:` class method, passing through as an argument the type of service required from the following options:

```
SLServiceTypeFacebook
SLServiceTypeTwitter
SLServiceTypeSinaWeibo
```

The following code, for example, verifies that Twitter service is available to the application:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) 
{
    // Device is able to send a Twitter message
}
```

This method call is optional and, in the event that an account for the specified social network has yet to be set up, the composer will simply take the user to the device’s Settings application where a Twitter account may be configured.
The next step is to create an instance of the `SLComposeViewController` class and supply an optional completion handler to be called when the composer screen is either cancelled by the user or used to send a message. Next, a range of methods may be called on the instance to initialize the object with the content of the message, including the initial text of the message, an image attachment and a URL:

- `setInitialText`: - Sets the initial text of the message on the `SLComposeViewController` instance.
- `addImage`: - Adds image files as attachments to the message.
- `addURL`: - Adds a URL to the message. The method automatically handles the URL shortening.
  Each of the above methods returns a Boolean result indicating whether the addition of content was successful.

Finally, when the message is ready to be presented to the user, the SLComposeViewController object is presented modally by calling the presentViewController: method of the parent view controller:

```
    SLComposeViewController *composeController = [SLComposeViewController
              composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

    [composeController setInitialText:@"Just found this great website"];
    [composeController addImage:postImage.image];
    [composeController addURL: [NSURL URLWithString: 
              @"http://www.website.com"]];

[self presentViewController:composeController 
          animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Once called, this method will present the composer view to the user primed with any text, image and URL contents pre-configured via the method calls. Once displayed, the user has the option to modify the text of the message, cancel the message, add location data or send the message. If a completion handler has been configured it will be called and passed a value indicating the action that was taken by the user within the composer view. Possible values are:

- `SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled` – The user cancelled the composition session by touching the Cancel button.
- `SLComposeViewControllerResultDone` – The user sent the composed message by touching the Send button.